# AWS Cloudfront Invalidation not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

I have a query related to invalidation.

I have a test page created on s3 bucket. The TTL set on Cloudfront is 1 week. But I have made some changes to the test page. I ran the invalidation as **'/*'** and expected all files to be evicted from the cache.

But still the pages are getting served from Cloudfront cache --> response header says **'x-cache: Hit from cloudfront'**

I am not sure what I am missing here, kindly suggest. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: What's the value corresponding to the `age` param in the response?

Comment: Basic question, but did you wait for the loading icon to complete? (it takes a couple of minutes for the cache to clear).

Answer (score 7):

My problem was I ran the following command on macOS:

```
aws --profile myprofile cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id someID --paths /*
```

Turns out my shell expanded `/*` to the following paths leading to a wrong invalidation:

```
/Applications
/home
/Volumes
/private
/Users
/bin
/sbin
/var
/dev
/usr
...
```

Escaping `/*` to `'/*'` fixed the issue:

```
aws --profile myprofile cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id someID --paths '/*'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, nothing seemed to work when using Github actions or even running the invalidation locally. And every tutorial explaining this actually doesn't use the '', I am almost inclined to believe that AWS just changed this, especially since I found this answer 15 minutes after you posted it

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

In my case everything was correctly connected(correct S3 bucket). But still I had this issue.

I fixed it by opening my CloudFront distribution and going in `Behaviors` tab. After that edit each behavior and change `Cache Policy` to `Managed-CachingDisabled`

This will disable caching entirely.

Comment: Vikas, unfortunately disabling cache is not solution to this. Its like someone saying fix my car and someone else says why use car at all.

Comment: I realise this is not a solution for prod but thank you for posting this, I couldn't get my dev cache to invalidate and this is even better.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying trying to invalidate an endpoint `/contact` in a `S3` static website fronted by `Cloudfront`

I went to `Cloudfront` -> `Distribution` -> `Invalidations` and input `/contact` and it wasn't working.

turns out, my `/contact` was actually served by `/contact/index.html` in `S3`.

To actually invalidate, I made my Invalidation:

```
/contact/*
```

Answer (score 0):

kindly ignore this question. I figured the issue. It was basic config issue and that ended up invalidating wrong bucket. Hence the data was always coming on from cache. Sorry for the trouble.